# App that can import google maps saved route to use as turn-by-turn navigation

Tags: google-maps, navigation

I built a driving path containing several destination points using google maps and would like to use it in a turn-by-turn GPS navigation app such as iGo.
Any existing app/s that can achieve that?

Thanks.

Comment: How did you build this path?  What format is it saved in?  I assume you're not using [Google Maps Navigation](http://www.google.com/mobile/navigation/) because you're outside the US.

Comment: Correct, Google Maps Navigation indeed doesn't work in my area, and I didn't know it's only available in the states (I'll be driving in France and thought it might work there). I used [Google Maps](http://maps.google.com/): added couple of destinations and moved part of the path so it'll go though several specific roads.

Comment: You could try this hacked version of maps: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=630887

Comment: I didn't know there's a hacked version to work in my area nice, thanks for that. It seems though it won't let me use my own route, nor can it work offline. I'm going to try MapQuest now.

Answer (score 2):

Osmand Is available on Google Play that allows navigating along a saved GPS log (in .gpx format).

You can export your Google Maps route (from maps.google.com) using http://www.elsewhere.org/journal/gmaptogpx/ to .gpx format. Push the .gpx to your phone (via bluetooth, email or USB) to /sdcard/osmand/tracks/ folder (important! Osmand only searches for .gpx files in this folder).

This is however not very straightforward and requires some steps... but I have used it for preparing motorcycle routes offline in advance for example.

In Osmand then:
Download your desired offline maps (the basic version allows 3 free downloads) and in the map view do: menu button -> navigate -> GPX -> choose your exported .gpx

Osmand is free software it's also possible to get it free of charge from f-droid.org's app store, but please support the author if you like it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of [openstreetmap](http://www.openstreetmap.org)?

Openstreetmap is a croudsource map database where users create a free service to use for navigation purposes.  There are many [android apps](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android) available that allow you to use openstreetmap maps to display many different things.  You can import a variety of different map types, as well as use different programs, such as [josm](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JOSM), to create these maps and routes to import to your choice of android application.

You can even help by [contributing](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Beginners%27_guide) new roads and updating existing information.